# Where can I find a proof that the numerical sign problem is NP-hard?

Tags: reference-request

I've reading up on the [numerical sign problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_sign_problem), and how a general solution is NP-Hard. I can't seem to find a proof of this, though.

Does anyone know where I can find a proof that the numerical sign problem is NP-Hard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof is purportedly offered in the paper: "Computational complexity and fundamental limitations to fermionic quantum Monte Carlo simulations". [Click here for the arXiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0408370). Here is the abstract:

> Quantum Monte Carlo simulations, while being efficient for bosons,
>   suffer from the "negative sign problem'' when applied to fermions -
>   causing an exponential increase of the computing time with the number
>   of particles. A polynomial time solution to the sign problem is highly
>   desired since it would provide an unbiased and numerically exact
>   method to simulate correlated quantum systems. Here we show, that such
>   a solution is almost certainly unattainable by proving that the sign
>   problem is NP-hard, implying that a generic solution of the sign
>   problem would also solve all problems in the complexity class NP
>   (nondeterministic polynomial) in polynomial time.

Apparently the folks in statistical mechanics are far more familiar than I am with this. [This post on the Physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11605/when-is-the-minus-sign-problem-in-quantum-simulations-an-obstacle) talks about the sign problem, too---and [here as well](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1453/great-unsolved-physics-problems/1966#1966).